# Python: Attempting to obtain a value in the next line at the eighth position

Tags: python

I have a lot of adsorption data and I am attempting to obtain the loading which is in the third position. Now that I have multiple components I have to call the component in the previous line to assure its the right component.

[image]

Comment: You need to post your code as text.

Comment: It would also help to ask the question in a more generic manner. Most people on this site won't know anything about absorption data, but can probably help you if you can find a way to ask the question without terms specific to that field.

Answer (score 2):

because it's 8th position you have to use val[7] not val[8].